# jQuery Class with numbered suffix

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this lump of code that I have been working on its getting late and I'm probably just being dumb but I cant figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I have a php loop that adds a number to the end of a class so that I can link a few divs together. So that when I click an element the other elements that end with that same number get affected.

So heres what I have:

```js
$('[class^=cl-]').on('click', function() {
  var num = $(this).match(/\d+$/)[0];
  $(".page-template-page-contact .active").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
  $('.c-map-' + num).addClass("active");
  $('.contacter-' + num).addClass("active");
});
```

```css
.nope {
  display: none;
}
div.active {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="nope active cl-0">A</div>
  <div class="nope active c-map-0">B</div>
  <div class="nope active contacter-0">C</div>
</div>

<div>
  <div class="nope cl-1">D</div>
  <div class="nope c-map-1">E</div>
  <div class="nope contacter-1">F</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Assuming that HTML is accurately representative, why not just use `$(this).siblings()`?

Comment: Or make your life easier by using the same class for all objects in a group. for example, group1 for all first div childre and group2 for all 2nd div children.

Comment: The HTML is not accurate. as mentioned its in a php loop and the html is allot more complex than shown.

Comment: Hi @Jules although that would work, The problem would technically still persist I have no ultimate control on the amount of divs reproduced in the loop I cant just liter my JS files with 100 versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i had understand, you need something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('*[class*="cl-"]').on('click', function() {
    console.log('fired');
  var num = $(this).attr('class').match(/\d+$/)[0];
  //console.log(num);

  $(".active").removeClass("active");
  //$(this).addClass("active");
  $('.cl-' + num).addClass("active");
  $('.c-map-' + num).addClass("active");
  $('.contacter-' + num).addClass("active");
 });
});
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/bellu/yLc7maqo/2/) a working fiddle.

I think that, [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) would be more appropriated in this contest.

Comment: Thank Bellu,That works perfectly I knew it could only be minor details I was missing. Was just up a bit late last night and couldn't see past it. Thanks Again.